# React Native Reanimated efficiently get max and min of subset of array of nodes

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

Is there an API in Reanimated to run a proc on part of an array of values?

I'm looking to use `react-native-reanimated` to animate the views of a potentially large and changing data set. In order to properly display the data, I must get the max and min values of the data between 2 indexes. I'd ideally like this logic to run on the native thread using the Reanimated APIs in order to achieve better performance as the indexes will change via a Pan Gesture.

This could be done by creating a max/min conditional node for every single data point. However, this seems like it would be very inefficient as there would need to be a max and min conditional for every single value in the data set. Here's an example of this logic

```
data.reduce(
      (acc, dataPoint) =>
        max(
          acc,
          cond(
            and(
              greaterOrEq(this.indexLeftBoundary, dataPoint.index),
              lessOrEq(this.indexRightBoundary, dataPoint.index),
            ),
            dataPoint.value,
            Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
          ),
        ),
      Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
    );
```

This approach will continue to become more resource intensive as the data set grows larger.